# My CSS menu is smaller on another page

Tags: html, css, menu

So, I've been making this website for practice, and I put a menu in there. It works just fine on both webpages, but it's smaller on the second one. Here's the code I have for the menu on the first one:

```
<div id = "movemenu"><ul class = "menu">
     <li class = "menu"><a href = "">About</a></li>
     <li class = "menu"><a href = "pali_pictures.html">Pictures</a></li>
     <li class = "menu"><a href = "">Contact</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

And here's the code for the second one:

```
<div id = "movemenu"><ul class = "menu">
    <li class = "menu"><a href = "pali_bio.html">About</a></li>
    <li class = "menu"><a href = "pali_pictures.html">Pictures</a></li>
    <li class = "menu"><a href = "">Contact</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.menu ul {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 1px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

.menu a {
    width: 6em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: #3399FF;
    padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
    border: 2px dotted darkblue;
}

.menu a:hover {
    background-color: #297ACC;
}

.menu li {
    display: inline;
}

#movemenu {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it looks smaller?

Comment: There should not be any difference. But you should not apply the same classes to your <ul> & <li>. To be honest you should only apply an id to your <div> and work with it. No need for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your CSS code is the same for both menus, perhaps your zoom level in your browser is different on one of the tabs you have opened. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to reset it to 100%. Did you check in several different browsers (optionally, with a tool like [browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org/) or [browserling.com](https://www.browserling.com/))?

Comment: ... Thanks. That.. was quite a dumb mistake of mine.